# What was the point of making rain after coming to Earth?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, thor-the-dark-world

In *Thor: The Dark World*, Jane and Darcy experienced a strange rain which wasn't falling on Jane. Later we saw that Thor was responsible for that. Why did Thor do that? What was the point of such god-ish entry?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that it was intentional as to my knowledge nowhere in Thor's myth was he able to control the weather. So my theory is that it was the dark power inside Jane that stopped her from getting wet or it was just a byproduct of the einstein rosen bridge that the asgardians use to travel the universe.
Or more likely he did it because well he's Thor...

Comment: In the norse mythology - when Thor rode there would be thunder, when he swung his hammer there would be lightning.

Comment: What the heck! In the movie, Thor did stop the rain after Darcy asked if he is behind the rain.

Comment: I thought it was the first (subtle) example of the Aether protecting itself.